# How to use multiple node.js files

Tags: node.js, web, server, visual-studio-2017

I am having trouble having my VS17 Node.js project use multiple node.js files to generate webpages. The have the standard http.createServer, but only one will generate. When I change the url to another Node file, it says it can't load that localhost.

Can any of you help? Does it have anything to do with package.json?

Comment: You should have one file that does a createServer() and that file require's all your other files/routes

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to node, you should consider using a framework like expressjs. It will abstract away a lot of the hard stuff so you can focus more on just making a website, and not reinventing the wheel.

https://expressjs.com/

There is a generator utility that will scaffold your project for you.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Install the generator

`npm install express-generator -g`

Run the generator

`express ./myapp/`

Then you will have a fully functional server that you can run with `npm start`